# Windows Middle click on titlebar

Tags: windows, windows-8, window-manager

Is there an application which provides similar functionality to modern linux distros in where if you middle click on a window's titlebar it is sent to the back of the stack in windows?

It seems like a superfluous thing, but I find it to be a very useful feature.

I don't mind if it's part of some premium software (well, within reason)

OS: Windows 8

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a program called eXtraButtons which can add additional buttons to window title bars, including one for "[Send to back](http://www.xtrabuttons.com/documentation/options/buttons-settings/send-to-back.html)" functionality.  It isn't a middle click, but perhaps it suits your needs?  Quote:

> When you press the button [image] in the caption on the window, you place window under others.

It also supports hotkeys for certain functions, so you could possibly use it in conjunction with another program that maps your middle mouse button to a key combination (unless you also use your middle button for something else.)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old question, but I just spent ages looking for this only to find out that it's one of the options in [Alt Drag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/) (which I already had installed).

It's under Configure -> "Mouse and keyboard" -> "Lower Windows by middle clicking on the title bars".

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This is great, the only issue is that I have to hold the Alt key, but that's a small drawback compared to having to click who knows where to not achieve the same functionality.

Comment: There is an extra checkbox so just middle click does the lowering. no Alt required. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpfZ2.png -- "Alt Drag" lowers the window upon button _down_.

Answer (score 0):

[Dexpot](https://dexpot.de/) can do this too. Its latest release is from 2016 though.

[image: settings]

The window is lowered when you *release* the configured mouse button. This is consistent with most other mouse button uses.

*Dexpot* primarily offers virtual desktops. It can also show a preview of your virtual desktops in the task bar.

[image: taskbar pager]

The virtual desktop switching accepts custom key bindings. There is a trick free up `Win+1..9` from `explorer.exe`, so they're available for your own purposes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DisabledHotkeys"="1234567890"
```